# I get an error when opening Nativescrupt Sidekick - Missing API tns.liveSyncService

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

I've just installed Nativescript Sidekick, when I try to run Sidekick I get this error. (node:10788) Error: Missing API. - tns.liveSyncService.

I've tried unistalling and reinstalling nativesript and node.js to no avail.
Please assist

Answer (score 0):

The Sidekick support for NativeScript@6.0 is still in progress and it will be released in a few days.

Meanwhile, if you need Sidekick - you have to downgrade to NativeScript@5.4 (`npm i -g nativescript@5.4.2`), if you need NativeScript@6.0 - you have to use it through the CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will give this a try

Comment: It works t, until I get this error, The current version of nativescript-dev-webpack (1.0.1) is not compatible with the used CLI: 5.4.2. Please upgrade your NativeScript CLI version (npm i -g nativescript)

Comment: nativescript-dev-webpack@1.0.1 is only nativescript@6.0.0 compatible, you need nativescript-dev-webpack@0.24.1 for nativescript@5.4.